# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 32, 3, 3], expected input[13, 4, 64, 768] to have 32 channels, but got 4 channels instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

I'm trying to train my model (custom model) in pytorch and I'm getting this error:
`RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 32, 3, 3], expected input[13, 4, 64, 768] to have 32 channels, but got 4 channels instead`
this is the code for my custom model:

```
class BERT_Arch(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, bert):
        super(BERT_Arch, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size = 3)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # this number is what i got when i printed the shape of x after max pooling #
        # 3 is the number of classes (labels) #
        self.fc = nn.Linear(13*31*383, 3)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax()

    def forward(self, sent_id, mask):
        bert_output = self.bert(sent_id, attention_mask=mask, output_hidden_states=True)
        x = bert_output[2]
        x = torch.stack([x[i] for i in range(len(x))])
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 13*31*383)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return self.softmax(x)
```

now to be honest, I don't know exactly how to use the conv2d because I don't understand the parameters of the function, and I tried reading everywhere and nothing ..
I don't know how to adjust my date shapes and sizes to make it as it should be for conv2d.
my batch size is 32
and my is 13 matrixes of the size (12, 768), that's why I used `torch.stack([x[i] for I in range(len(x))])`.
**you can ignore the numbers(parameters) that I already set in my code, I was just trying to make it work.**
Can someone help me to set the parameters ? I'm really confused about this.

Comment: Try to set `self.conv = nn.Conv2d(4, 32, kernel_size = 3)`.

Comment: It gives me the following error : `RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 4, 3, 3], expected input[13, 32, 64, 768] to have 4 channels, but got 32 channels instead`